# How to install ANT 1.9.6?

Tags: software-installation, source-packages, apache-ant

I want to install ANT from downloaded zip: apache-ant-1.9.6-bin.zip.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the Windows file you downloaded. You need the [.tar.gz](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) and that download has a file named INSTALL with a link to the installation manual:

> For installation instructions see the manual in the docs subdirectory
>   or online at http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html.

It is a binairy download so all you need to to do un-tar it to a location (I would advice something like `/opt/apache-ant-1.9.6/` with a symlink to `/opt/apache-ant/` so you can install several verions).

You need JDK (1.7+ adviced) and set a few things:

- Add the `bin` directory to your path
- Set the `ANT_HOME` environment variable to the directory where you installed Ant.
- Optionally, set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

Example:

- Assume Ant is installed in `/opt/apache-ant/`. The following sets up the environment:

  ```
  export ANT_HOME=/opt/apache-ant/
  export JAVA_HOME=/opt/apache-ant/jdk1.7.0_51
  export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
  ```

The link to the manual also has instructions on checking if all went well.